# what is the use of plus sign in a given code below?

Tags: java

I am a beginner in programming and have been seeing plus signs like +sum, +result, but not sure what is the use of it.
could anyone put some light on this issue for me.

```
    SimpleIO.println("Enter gear: ");
    gear = SimpleIO.readInteger();
    SimpleIO.println("Enter power: ");
    power = SimpleIO.readInteger();
    System.out.println("speed= " +power*gear);`
```

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plus operator has a double meaning. Its a concatination operator as well. As the "speed=" is of type String the "power*gear" (Integer?) is converted to a String as well.

Comment: so, it basically make the both parts of same data type??

Comment: @LaxmanKunwor yes. To be more specific, to String datatype. But only for that instruction (line). Meaning it doesn't permanently change the datatype.

Comment: thanks, now at least i have the idea behind why its done.

Comment: @LaxmanKunwor : You are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

It is exactly what you think it is.
The line of code says "print out the sum of the string in quotes and result of 'power*gear'".
So, say 'power' is 1 and 'gear' is 2, the print would be "speed= 2"